# Cryptolocker: Derive Key Mathematically From A Decrypted Copy of a File?

Tags: encryption, virus

Would it be possible to derive the key, if you have a decrypted version of a file, let's say this file, as an example:

"C:\Windows\ehome\en-US\epgtos.txt"

Or do cryptolocker and it's class of virus not infect files other than user's documents, which are unlikely to exist on a similar machine?

AFAIK all files on a single machine share the same key.

Comment: No;  Its not possible derive the key from a single file.  There is a service that exists that (might) already has the key.  They were able to get it because of a flaw in `Cryptolocker".  The reason the service works is because they try every key and attempt to decrypt the file.

Comment: If you could a) that would be completely useless encryption, and b) the AV vendors would have already figured that out. ;)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answers. I was thinking that it was the equivalent of having a linux /etc/shadow crypted password and the decrypted password. It's probably more like having the crypted password and having a file that is encrypted with that same password, but without access to the non-crypted password.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) on the encryption algorithm used. It used to be possible a few decades ago (e.g. it's how the Enigma was broken), but more or less impossible against modern encryption algorithms; in fact, it's one of the first things that an algorithm's designer would defend against.

That said, specifically against CryptoLocker, [supposedly someone has figured out](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/08/06/decryptolocker/) how to derive the key from an *encrypted* file. The article says that it's done using a cache of decryption keys that was discovered on a C&C server.

Comment: I'm curious why hasn't anyone tried to hack into their servers? The FBI located dread pirate's server. I'm sure there's something. Smart hackers have been hacked before.